# Where do I download Java development binaries (JDK) for Windows XP 32 bit

Tags: jdk

I am trying to download the jdk for windows but the link [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html) is not working. is there a different place to download?

Comment: It's working for me here. Have you accepted the license agreement?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to *Accept License Agreement* and click on the red down arrow.

Alternatively, [here's a mirror link from CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Java-Development-Kit/3000-2218_4-12091.html).

And [this is the original link from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html).

Comment: I think it might be my work proxy. Has an issue with the exe extension. is there another reputable place to download as zip besides cnet?

Comment: @Luke101 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619662/where-can-i-get-the-latest-jre-jdk-as-a-zip-file-i-mean-no-exe-installer